# change elements of css with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some javascript code that changes the background colour of a CSS element called white. I need to change several other things like text colour in the li elements etc but can`t seem to do it? I have tried changing the class but that does not work either?

The CSS is :

```
.white{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  z-index: 99999;
  background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  width:100%;
  height:72px;
  }


.white ul{
  margin-top:20px;
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0;
}

.white ul li{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  color:red;
}
```

And the JS is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (scroll > 72) {
        $(".white").css("background" , "#00a4ff");
      }
      if (scroll < 72) {
        $(".white").css("background-color" , "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)");
      }

  })
})
```

Comment: Please share HTML also

Comment: It would be great of you can create a snippet or a fiddle to explain your problem

Comment: Can you specify what you need to change and share HTML markup

Comment: It is a bad practice to modify your CSS file within `jQuery`. My recommendation would be to use something along the lines of `.white .belowScroll { background: #00a4ff }` and then just using [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to set it.

Comment: The above should work as long as ".white" target is correct. Are you sure $(window).scrollTop(); is hitting both sides of 72 and making the changes? But as Alex said, its a bad, bad practice, this would not pass code review from me.

Comment: You need to separate your two (potential) issues and confirm which is causing the problem.  It could be that the `$(window).scroll` is not firing - if it is, then remove that part from the question and change to something like a simple button click.  Or it could be that you're targeting the wrong element and expecting something to change that doesn't.  eg you're using both `background` and then `background-color` where they should both be the 2nd.

Comment: Rather than changing the color of a Css Element what you can do is u can style html control as: $("p").css("background-color", "yellow");